# Using Paypal API Certificate with ActiveMerchant

Tags: paypal, activemerchant

I'm trying to implement paypal service using ActiveMerchant in my app. My developler's paypal account is set up for API certificate credentials. The following code works perfectly well when used with API signature but gives me an error when I try to implement API certificate. Can someone please help?

```
PAYPAL_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/paypal_cert_dev.pem")
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test 
  paypal_options = {
    :login => "****************",
    :password => "**************",
    :certificate => PAYPAL_CERT_PEM
  }
  ::STANDARD_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(paypal_options)
end
```

The Error :

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemerchant-1.12.1/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal/paypal_common_api.rb:72:in `initialize': An API Certificate or API Signature is required to make requests to PayPal (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured out where I went wrong. I checked into the ActiveMerchant doc and found that I should be using :pem instead of :certificate. So, the code should look like -

```
PAYPAL_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/paypal_cert_dev.pem")
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test 
  paypal_options = {
    :login => "****************",
    :password => "**************",
    :pem => PAYPAL_CERT_PEM
  }
  ::STANDARD_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(paypal_options)
end
```